# How to write a string and than columns from part of file?

Tags: awk

How to print a string and that columns from some point of file?

Input file:

```
here is
text with
information
pc/desktop/folder/name
here end -------------
45 1 2 3 
2  5 5 5
```

For finding required string:

```
-F'[/.]' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i=="folder"){print $(i+1)}}}'
```

for printing columns

```
BEGIN{flag=""} /end/{flag=1;next} !/end/ && /[a-zA-Z]+/{flag=""} flag{print $1, $2}
```

I expect

```
name
45 1
2  5
```

What I want is to print columns from a file and above it add a name. Original files consist of some text in a head and then there are columns with numbers.

Comment: [@Elisabeth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10498690/elisabeth) don't make up alternate names for yourself, pick one name and stick with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this

```
$ awk '/\/folder\//{n=split($0,a,"/"); print a[n]} f{print $1,$2} / end /{f=1}' file
```

assumes "folder" will appear before "end".

Comment: Thank you and please how it would be when the end isn't the last word? There are ---- after it and on the next line columns with numbers start.